# use function to plot in shiny

Tags: r, function, plot, shiny

I use a function to plot in R, because this is pretty large code for the plot (hexagonals etc). For the sake of neat code I put this in a function.

It is about a SOM algorithm , that does not really matter for now, but I create the data I need, then I normally plot it with the following code:

```
mydata <- som_model$codes
  var <- 1
  title <- names(som_model$data)[var]
  dataplot <- matrix(mydata[,var],nrow=gridsize,ncol=gridsize,byrow=TRUE)

  source('plotHexMap.R')
  plotHexMap(dataplot,title,gridsize)
```

So now I want to do this in Shiny:

```
 observe({
  if(input$plottrained>0){

        var <- 1
        title <- names(som_model$data)[var]
        dataplot<-matrix(mydata[,var],nrow=gridsize,ncol=gridsize,byrow=TRUE)

       source("plotHexMap.R")
       output$plot1 <-renderPlot({plotHexMap(dataplot,title,gridsize)})       

    }

  })
```

Ok so this does not work, but when I just write the plot to a global variable (with <<-) it does exist and I can see it in the plots, so by doing this:

```
 observe({
    if(input$plottrained>0){

        var <- 1
        title <- names(som_model$data)[var]
        dataplot<-matrix(mydata[,var],nrow=gridsize,ncol=gridsize,byrow=TRUE)

       source("plotHexMap.R")
       plot1 <<-renderPlot({plotHexMap(dataplot,title,gridsize)})       

    }

  })
```

What am I missing here? what does shiny need that normal R environment does not to plot this from function?

would really appreciate any help with this! Thanks in advance,

Pieter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `observe`, try `renderPlot` in server:

```
output$myplot <- renderPlot({
    if(input$plottrained>0){
        var <- 1
        title <- names(som_model$data)[var]
        dataplot<- matrix(mydata[,var],nrow=gridsize,ncol=gridsize,byrow=TRUE)

       source("plotHexMap.R", local = TRUE)     #assuming this file is actually local for you
       plot1 <- plotHexMap(dataplot,title,gridsize)       
    }
    else{return(NULL)}
  })
```

And then plotOutput in the ui:

```
plotOutput('myplot')
```

Comment: Now unfortunately I just can not use my loop any more to plot multiple of these figures. But I do not have an exact question on this yet, as I was doing this with a dynamic renderUI and then plotting inside that multiple times.. Or do you happen to know how to easily plot more of these with a loop?